# During compilation of 32 bit binaries in to 64 bit fedora 17 in c++ getting error :

Tags: c++

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgtest.so when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgtest.a when searching for -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/../lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/../lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgtest_main.so when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libgtest_main.a when searching for -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgtest_main
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
```

I have tried so many options:

1. tried installng Gcc multilib "yum install glibc-devel.i686 glibc.i686"
   It is not working
2. Also tried installing  sudo chmod -R 777 libusb-compat-0.1.5
   not working

Please answer if anyone having the solution for this.
I want to compile our Gtest 32 bit object files of builtroot on 64 bit platform on fedora 17.

Comment: Could binary be 64 bits?

Comment: Of you do `file /lib/libgtest.so` (or one of the others), you'll probably find that it is a 64-bit binary. Can you post your link command?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to install `libgtest-devel.i686` (or whatever it may be called)

Comment: Hii..I have tried to get the type of libgtest.so ... It is giving below details:[root@localhost lib]# file "libgtest.so.0.0.0"
libgtest.so.0.0.0: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xa821ce6f8ad411b2d6cbea24cf1421d5928195ec, not stripped